# What is the correct way to tell if a screen is compatible with my laptop?

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop, compatibility, toshiba-laptop, laptop-display

I have an old IBM thinkpad Z61t, and I want to upgrade the screen to one from an even older Toshiba laptop.  The screens are both very different sizes, and probably different resolutions, but the same aspect ratio (16:9).  The connectors are all the same and it plugs in just fine, but I haven't booted it up yet because I don't know if its a good idea.  I don't know whether or not it'll work, and I don't want to risk wrecking the screen.  I do know a bit about hardware - I've completely dissected a number of laptops and scavenged parts to build one that's better than any of the original ones were, so I do know what I'm doing.  I'm just wondering if it'll work, and, if not, what the worst that can happen would be.

Comment: This a serious question?  If the screens are different sizes, even if the connectors are the same, how do you expect to use the laptop if the physical size of the display cannot be mounted in the laptop?

Comment: I don't care about the size or whether or not I can close my laptop, I'm just wondering if its compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work - and if it doesn't, the screen just won't turn on.

Computers query the resolutions of monitors to negotiate the best possible resolution supported by the monitor (even for VGA connections - using [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)).   EDID predates your laptop.

Unless you specifically override the negotiation, the screen can't be damaged, and even then, its most likely a modern screen will handle it - either by not turning on or by scaling the content.

Comment: It works! :) Although, as Ramhound stated, it doesn't fit in the laptop casing, so using it is a bit of a hassle.